# Trying to add separate page numbers to appendices?

Tags: microsoft-word, page-numbers

I have added section breaks and I can get the page numbers to re-start from 1, but I want them to show the total count of that section - e.g. "1 of 5" instead of "1 of 48". 
Is this even possible? I have multiple appendices and I have made it more of a mess than a success. 
TYIA

Answer (score 0):

Yes, so long as you have section breaks set up. Go to the page numbering in your document, right-click on the final page number and select *Edit Field*. It should currently show that it is set to the *NumPages* field, which is a total count of page numbers. Scroll down the list and select *SectionPages*, which will show the total pages in the section.

[image]